# How to get suggestions in findBy method for data JPA in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-tool-suite

While writing this method in interface `public List<Employee> findByEmpNameAndEmpSal(String name,Double sal);`
So After **findByEmpName** when i keep cursor then i should get suggestions like (and,or,in,GreaterThan,LessThan... many more).
when i  practice DataJPA concepts. I saw youtube video when i keep cursor after `findByEmpName` he was getting suggesstions.
Now if you see below screenshot where my cursor after EmpName **I want data using name and salary**.

[image]

Comment: Does hitting ctl + space bring up the suggestions?

Comment: NO @JWoodchuck, Its saying "No SWT template proposals" ,"NO template proposals", "NO chain template proposals"

Comment: One thing to try is restoring the default content assist options: 'Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced'

Comment: After doing it this as well.. Its behaving same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing auto complete support for Spring Data in Spring Tools 4 is very limited and doesn't provide the support that you mentioned yet. The corresponding enhancement request is: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/107

Comment: Okay, Sounds great. We dont have support for STS 4 yet.